# Convert dictionary to multiple arrays

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

How can I convert a dictionary like this :

```
var myDictionary: Dictionary = ["Data1":"Value1", "Data2":"Value2", "Data3":"Value3"]
```

Into two arrays like that :

```
var myArray1 = ["Data1", "Data2", "Data3"]
var myArray2 = ["Value1", "Value2", "Value3"]
```

I tried to do it with :

```
myDictionary.values
```

and :

```
myDictionary.keys
```

But didn't worked...

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: For future reference "*But didn't worked*" is never a sufficient description of a problem – did it give you a compile time error? A runtime exception? An unexpected output? Set your house on fire?

Comment: Also duplicate of [Swift Dictionary: Get values as array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26988167/swift-dictionary-get-values-as-array/26988168#26988168)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let someKeys = [String](myDictionary.keys)
//It is only [String] because the keys are Strings

let someValue = [String](myDictionary.values)
//It is only [String] because the values are String
```

If I had a `[Int:String]()` then it would be

```
let someKeys = [Int](someKeys.keys)
```

because key:Value

**Edit**

I totally forgot, nice job @originaluser2

You can also do

```
let array = Array(myDictionary.keys)
let array2 = Array(myDictionary.values)
```

and it will do the hard work for you.

Comment: Or even better, use the `Array(...)` initialiser and let Swift infer the type