# populating array with dictionary

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, nested

I have an array like below, which contains an Array called   "OrderDetails", which is I think a dictionary not array(I'm not sure what to call it.
in another vc, I have to create OrderDetails and then put it here in dataa.
In the other VC that I have to create OrderDetails, I have a table view, which means the data of the table (some of them) should be set to the array. could somebody help me how should I make that array?

```
 let dataa = [            "Id":0,
                                 "CustomrId": 111,
                                 "PriceVariableId": item[1].priceVariableIdCore,
                                 "PaymentTypeId":item[1].paymentVariableIdCore,
                                 "RefCo":item[1].refcoCore,
                                 "OrderNo":1122,
                                 "ReciverId":0,
                                 "DlvProvinceId":UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: constantAddress.stateId),
                                 "DlvCityId": UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: constantAddress.cityId),
                                 "DlvAddress": UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: constantAddress.addressLine),
                                 "DlvZip": UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: constantAddress.postalCode),
                                 "DlvTel": UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: constantAddress.telephone),
                                 "DlvMobile": UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: constantAddress.mobile),
                                 "TtIsSingle": TAK,
                                 "TtIsDouble": JOFT,
                                 "TtIsTrailer":TREILI,
                                 "Description":EntTozihat.text,

                                 "OrderDetails":["OrderDetailId":0 ,
                                                 "Qty":0,
                                                 "UnitPrice":600]

                                 ]

"OrderDetails":[("OrderDetailId":0 ,"Qty":0,"UnitPrice":600),(),()]
```

**update**:

I'm creating the OrderDetails like below:

```
    for _ in 0...item.count {

            let dict = ["Id": 0,
                        "Qty":item[indexPath.row].quantityCore ,
                        "UnitPrice":item[indexPath.row].feeCore ,
                        "GoodId":item[indexPath.row].goodIdCore,] as [String : Any]
            listArray.append(dict)

        }
        print("JACK=  \(listArray)")
```

I have to problem here!!! 1) I'm using this right into the "cellForRowAt" with "dequeueReusableCell" which means as many ro as I have it would return  the data like below:

> JACK=  [["Id": 0, "GoodId": 0, "UnitPrice": 0.0, "Qty": 0.0], ["Id": 0, "GoodId": 0, "UnitPrice": 0.0, "Qty": 0.0], ["Id": 0, "GoodId": 0, "UnitPrice": 0.0, "Qty": 0.0], ["Id": 0, "GoodId": 0, "UnitPrice": 0.0, "Qty": 0.0], ["Id": 0, "GoodId": 0, "UnitPrice": 0.0, "Qty": 0.0], ["Id": 0, "GoodId": 0, "UnitPrice": 0.0, "Qty": 0.0], ["Id": 0, "GoodId": 0, "UnitPrice": 0.0, "Qty": 0.0], ["Id": 0, "GoodId": 0, "UnitPrice": 0.0, "Qty": 0.0], ["Id": 0, "GoodId": 0, "UnitPrice": 0.0, "Qty": 0.0], ["Id": 0, "GoodId": 0, "UnitPrice": 0.0, "Qty": 0.0], ["Id": 0, "GoodId": 0, "UnitPrice": 0.0, "Qty": 0.0], ["Id": 0, "GoodId": 0, "UnitPrice": 0.0, "Qty": 0.0], ["Id": 0, "GoodId": 0, "UnitPrice": 0.0, "Qty": 0.0], ["Id": 0, "GoodId": 0, "UnitPrice": 0.0, "Qty": 0.0], ["Id": 0, "GoodId": 0, "UnitPrice": 0.0, "Qty": 0.0], ["Id": 0, "GoodId": 0, "UnitPrice": 0.0, "Qty": 0.0], ["Id": 0, "GoodId": 0, "UnitPrice": 0.0, "Qty": 0.0], ["Id": 0, "GoodId": 0, "UnitPrice": 0.0, "Qty": 0.0], ["Id": 0, "GoodId": 0, "UnitPrice": 0.0, "Qty": 0.0], ["Id": 0, "GoodId": 0, "UnitPrice": 0.0, "Qty": 0.0], ["Id": 0, "GoodId": 0, "UnitPrice": 0.0, "Qty": 0.0], ["Id": 0, "GoodId": 0, "UnitPrice": 0.0, "Qty": 0.0], ["Id": 0, "GoodId": 0, "UnitPrice": 0.0, "Qty": 0.0], ["Id": 0, "GoodId": 0, "UnitPrice": 0.0, "Qty": 0.0], ["Id": 0, "GoodId": 0, "UnitPrice": 0.0, "Qty": 0.0]]

the print() you see above print 4 time becuase I have 4 row!!!

the other problem 2) is that I don't know why it return that much data in each "JACK="

first: I need to know how to use the code outside of the "cellForRowAt"
second:why I get thismuch data in "JACK"

Comment: Duplicate:
Array from dictionary values: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26988167/swift-dictionary-get-values-as-array
Array from dictionary keys:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386093/array-from-dictionary-keys-in-swift

Comment: The `dataa` is the dictionary and `OrderDetails` seems dictionary as well. You can get the values: `dataa["OrderDetails"]?.map({ $0.value })`

Comment: @ShalvaAvanashvili what does dataa["OrderDetails"]?.map({ $0.value }) do

Comment: @ShalvaAvanashvili updated the question

Comment: @Kamil.S actually I have an array and the elements are supposed to  be a dictionary

Comment: @ItanHant `dataa` in your current code snippet is a dictionary not an array.

Comment: Yes the main one is a dictionary, but my question is about the OrderDetails

Comment: @ItanHant `dataa["OrderDetails"]?.map({ $0.value })` it will extract the values from the OrderDetails as an array. Then you will use that array in your tableview.

Comment: I don't want to use it in table view! I want to put the data from table view into the array!

Comment: First, it looks like this data is used many times. Why not creating a struct for it. Second, as pointed out correctly, this is a dictionary of type `[String: Any]`. You can simply get the order details by accessing it on it’s key: `guard let dataa[“OrderDetails”] as? [String: Int] else { // do something to fail, e.g. throw }`.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like so:

```
 let orderDetails = dataa["OrderDetails"]!
```

If you're not sure whether that entry exists or not you could unwrap it safely:

```
if let orderDetails = dataa["OrderDetails"] {
    //use orderDetails
}
```

Or if you need it in the rest of the scope:

```
guard let orderDetails = dataa["OrderDetails"] else {
    fatalError("Couldn't unwrap the order details")
}
//use orderDetails
```

That way `orderDetails` would be a dictionary of type `[String: Int]`.

Comment: You should not use force unwrapping, but rather `guard` or work with optional types instead

Comment: It is on purpose, yes

Comment: Should be accepted as answer. For me the only “better” way for order information would be storing it into a struct, but that’s way beyond the question.

Comment: @cr0ss Yes it does look like a struct is a better way to structure the data. generally speaking, using dictionaries of type [Type1: Any] is a sign of bad data-modeling.

Comment: here you are telling how to put OrderDetails in dataa, my problem is how to create the OrderDetails

Comment: @ItanHant actually this gets that array from the `dataa` dictionary.

Comment: so I first I need to create the Array and then implement it in to the dataa

Comment: I just added something to the question , pls check that to to clarify my question